# All this information

Tags: uncountable-nouns

Is it correct to say `all this information`? I know that the noun `information` is uncountable, and subsequently preceded by `this` instead of `these`, but I wonder whether the full phrase `*all* this information` is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are plenty of contexts where this expression sounds natural.

> *Where did you find all this information?*

That question implies that someone has amassed a lot of information, and the asker is wondering where it came from (or perhaps marveling that a researcher was able to compile such an impressive trove).

> *All this information is irrelevant now.*

That means there is some information available, but someone is complaining that it's not the information that is needed, or that perhaps the information has expired.

> Look! I got a list of all the white Mustangs registered in Alabama.
>
> That would be great – except we just learned that the getaway car was registered in Arizona, not Alabama. All this information is irrelevant now.

Interestingly enough, you can omit the word *all*, and the sentences still sound fine; it's not a required word:

> *Where did you find this information?*
>
> *This information is irrelevant now.*

I like how NOAD defines *all*:

> **all** (*predeterminer*) used to refer to the whole quantity or extent of a particular group or thing : *she left all her money to him*

So *all* in this context is simply used for emphasis. It implies there is a lot of information, not just a little bit. You probably wouldn't use *all this information* if you were only talking about one or two little facts.

Answer (score 3):

All this information is correct.

The sentence is absolutely correct.  The word "all" has been used as a predeterminer before the determiner "this" followed by an uncountable noun "information". The pattern predeterminer + determiner + countable/uncountable noun is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly legitimate to use "all" with uncountable nouns. Just because something isn't countable doesn't mean that you might not have more or less of it, including the possibility of having all of it. "All the water in the world", "All the freedom that one could hope for", etc.